How Can this Limit be really Evaluated?
$$
\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{x + x^2 + x^3 +\ldots+ x^n - n}{x-1}
$$
So the problem I am facing is that the limit of this function doesn't exist because this function is not two sided.
Limit from the left is:
$$ \lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{x + x^2 + x^3 + \ldots + x^n - n}{x - 1} = (-3 + 2n + n^2) \cdot \infty $$
How I solved for the limit from left:
The limit can be written as:
$$
\frac{x + x^2 + x^3 + \ldots + x^n - n}{x - 1} = \frac{(x - n)(2x + n + 1)}{2(x - 1)(x + 1)}
$$
$$
\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{(x - n)(2x + n + 1)}{2(x - 1)(x + 1)} = \frac{1}{2} \lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{(x - n)(2x + n + 1)}{(x - 1)(x + 1)}
$$
$$
\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{(x - n)(2x + n + 1)}{(x - 1)(x + 1)} = \lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{1}{x - 1} \times \frac{1}{x + 1} \times (x - n) \times (2x + n + 1)
$$
$$
= \left(\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{1}{x - 1}\right) \left(\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{1}{x + 1}\right) \left(\lim_{x \to 1^-} (x - n)\right) \left(\lim_{x \to 1^-} (2x + n + 1)\right)
$$
$$
= \frac{\left(\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{1}{x - 1}\right) \left(\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{1}{x + 1}\right) \left(\lim_{x \to 1^-} (x - n)\right) \left(\lim_{x \to 1^-} (2x + n + 1)\right)}{2}
$$
$$
2x + n + 1 \text{ is continuous at } x = 1
$$
$$
\frac{\left(\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{1}{x - 1}\right) \left(\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{1}{x + 1}\right) \left(\lim_{x \to 1^-} (x - n)\right) (n + 3)}{2}
$$
$$
x - n \text{ is continuous at } x = 1
$$
$$
\frac{\left(\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{1}{x - 1}\right) \left(\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{1}{x + 1}\right) (-n + 1) (n + 3)}{2}
$$
$$
 \frac{1}{x + 1} \text{ is continuous at } x = 1
$$
$$
\frac{\frac{1}{2} \left(\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{1}{x - 1}\right) (-n + 1) (n + 3)}{2}
$$
$$
\text{Since } \lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{1}{x - 1} = -\infty \text{ and } x - 1 < 0 \text{ for all } x \text{ just to the left of } x = 1, \text{ we have } \lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{1}{x - 1} = -\infty:
$$
$$
\frac{-\infty (-n + 1) (n + 3)}{2 \times 2}
$$
$$
\frac{\text{(large negative number)} (-n + 1) (n + 3)}{2 \times 1/2} = -\infty (-n + 1) (n + 3)
$$
This can be further solved to get the given limit from the left above
Limit from the right is:
$$ \lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{x + x^2 + x^3 + \ldots + x^n - n}{x - 1} = (3 - 2n - n^2) \cdot \infty $$
Steps for limit from right are similar to the limit from left. I guess there is no need to write that all again.
But can't this question be also solved like this:
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{x + x^2 + x^3 + \ldots + x^n - (1 + 1 + 1 + \cdots + 1 \text{ (n times)})}{x - 1}$$
$$
= \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{(x - 1) + (x^2 - 1) + (x^3 - 1) + \ldots + (x^n - 1)}{x - 1}
$$
$$
= \lim_{x \to 1} \left[ \frac{x^1 - 1^1}{x - 1} + \frac{x^2 - 1^2}{x - 1} + \frac{x^3 - 1^3}{x - 1} + \ldots + \frac{x^n - 1^n}{x - 1} \right]
$$
$$
\text{Since } \lim_{x \to a} \frac{x^n - a^n}{x - a} = na^{n-1},
$$
$$
= 1 \cdot 1^0 + 2 \cdot 1^1 + 3 \cdot 1^2 + \cdots + n \cdot 1^{n-1}
$$
$$
= 1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots + n
$$
$$
= \frac{n(n + 1)}{2}
$$
Now I am confused which approach is correct. Both seems equally right to me. Most probably I am missing some important concept to differentiate between these two cases because this type of questions are very common. Please let me know whatever the case is.
Edit: Added the steps for limit from left. Just to mention, actually, we are only allowed to use the core defination of limits and functions and their rules to solve this question. That's why this approach. Also, sorry for the bad formatting, I am not really good at it.
Edit2: I feel like my question is getting misunderstood. I am not interested to know how we can find the limit of the given function/equation in different different ways.
If we have established that the right-hand limit and the left-hand limit are not equal, how can the limit of the function exist? This is my primary concern. I may not have articulated this question clearly before, but my intent is solely to understand this concept. I am aware of various methods to evaluate limits, but I am specifically asking how a limit of a function can exist when it is not two-sided. To clarify, I am interested in understanding how a limit of a function can exist if we have the conditions:
$ \lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) = L_1 $
$ \lim_{x \to a^-} f(x) = L_2 $
where $L_1 \neq L_2$. For a limit to exist, $L_1$ and $L_2$ must be equal.

how do you get those expression for the right/left limits?

It's hard to tell where you went wrong when there is no work for where your supposed one sided limits come from. Also, an approach you can use for the limit is polynomial long division.

You haven't told us how you got $(-3+2n+n^2).$

In any even, you don't need to break this up. If $f(x)=x+\cdots+x^n,$ then $f(1)=n,$ and this limit is $f'(1).$

Added the steps. Sorry.

Why not put $y=x-1$ so that $x=y+1$, then the limit is as $y\to 0$ and everything drops out nicely: I have always thought this a useful trick for some of these limit computations.

The equation $\frac{x + x^2 + x^3 + \ldots + x^n - n}{x - 1} = \frac{(x - n)(2x + n + 1)}{2(x - 1)(x + 1)}$ is not true, which is probably the root of your troubles.

@MishaLavrov here the solved proof is https://www.mathcha.io/editor/wZnD1t0GSWNt34LE3Vfgyv09YtPW85os1XBqqO. Writing that all there would have been a mess.

Not at all clear what you are doing there either. Just multiply the equation by the denominators and you will see that both sides are polynomials in $x$ of different degrees.

In mathcha, the third step: "Now let's simplify the right side of the equation": where does that expression come from?  What does the upper limit of that sum mean?

The expression you're looking at is $\frac{(x-1) + (x^2-1) + \dots + (x^n-1)}{x-1}$. This is a sum of $n$ ratios. Each of the form $\frac{x^k-1}{x-1}$ for some $k=1,\dots,n$.

If you know the derivative of $x^k$, you'll have $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x^k-1}{x-1} =\frac{d}{dx} (x^k)|_{x=1}=k$, and therefore the limit exists and is equal to $1+\dots + k= (k+1)k/2$.

Otherwise, observe that $x^k -1 = (1+\dots +x^{k-1} ) (x-1)$. Therefore $\frac{x^k-1}{x-1} = 1+\dots +x^{k-1}$ for $x\ne 1$, which, again, implies that the limit $\lim_{x\to1} \frac{x^k-1}{x-1}=k$.



Classic analysis.

But isn't it also true that limit from right ≠ limit from left, which is the primary test for knowing if a function has a limit or not. How can the limit of this function exists when we have proved that limit from right ≠ limit from left? This is my main question. I guess I didn't presented it on the post clearly, but I only want to know this. I am aware about the different approaches we can take to find the limit but how can a limit of a function exists when it is not two-sided?

The limit from the left is equal to the limit from the right which is exactly what I wrote.

@Kine You are correct that the limit only exists if the right and left limits exist and are equal.  But your calculation of the left and right limits was incorrect.

Your calculation of the one-sided limits are just incorrect - not sure how you got (x-n)(2x+n-1) on the numerator, etc.

Consider the function $f(x)=x+x^2+\dots x^n$.
Then $f(1)=n$, so the limit in question is
$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1} $$
This limit exists since $f$ is differentiable at $1$ and is equal to $f'(1)$.
But $$f'(x)=1+2x+3x^2+\dots+nx^{n-1}$$
So $$f'(1)=1+2+3+\dots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

An option using the Binomial expansion
Rewrite the numerator as:
$[1+(x-1)]^1+[1+(x-1)]^2$
$+..... [1+(x-1)]^n-n;$
Expand each term, $k \ge 1$,
$[1+(x-1)]^k=1+k(x-1)+$
$((k(k-1))/2!) (x-1)^2+....$
Adding the terms $k=1,..,n,$ subtracting $n$, and dividing by the denominator $(x-1)$, gives
$1+2+3+....+n + $ terms of order of
$(x-1)$ and higher.
Now take the limit.
Can you finish?

The numerator is a polynomial with factor $(x-1)$
Apply synthetic division to the numerator:
\begin{array}{c|rrr}&1&1&1&\cdots& 1 & -n\\1&&1&2&\cdots&n-1&n\\\hline\\&1&2&3&\cdots&n&0\\\end{array}
Factor $(x-1)$ from the numerator:
$(x-1)(x^{n-1} + 2x^{n-2} + 3x^{n-3} + \cdots + (n-1)x + n)$
$(x-1)$ factor cancels.
And evaluate as $x$ approaches $1.$

How do we know ahead of actual division that the numerator is divisable by $(x-1)$?

@Trunk - Evaluate it at $x=1$. Roots of polynomials correspond to factors.

Smart. And Kine might even have school experience of using this trick when finding the single root needed for getting other roots by Horner's method. But would a person of Kine's experience think of that trick in the context of polynomial division ? Clearly to find a finite limit at $x \to 1$ one has to find a way to get the $(x-1)$ out from under the line. To my mind, a trial division would be the workman-like way to approach the final solution that you got.

I am not able to follow at all your first two attempts at getting the limit, I am sorry to say.
Straight-up application of the de l'Hôpital Rule, i.e.
$$\lim _{ x \to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim _{ x \to c} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$
is the only other approach I could conceive of trying to evaluate this limit. It works as well as the trick you correctly noted.
The derivative of the numerator $(x+x^2+ \ldots +x^n-n)$ when evaluated at $x=1$ is
$$1+2(1)+\ldots + i(1)^{i-1}+ \ldots + n(1)^{n-1} = 1+2+\ldots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
whereas the derivative of the denominator $(x-1)$ as x $\to 1$ is simply $1$.
Thus by the de l'Hôpital Rule:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} (\frac{x+x^2+x^3+ \ldots + x^n - n}{x-1}) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}/1 = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
which is what you already observed in your last and correct approach.

That's the main point. We are not allowed to use L Hopital's Rule. Well at least that is what we have been told to do. Only the basic definition of limits and functions and their rules are allowed be to used.

No need of L'Hospital's Rule here. The denominator is $x-1$, so it is the definition of a derivative at $1$.

By $x=1+y$ with $y\to 0$ we have
$$ \frac{x + x^2 + x^3 +\ldots+ x^n - n}{x-1}=\frac{(1+y)+(1+y)^2+\ldots+(1+y)^n-n}{y}=$$
$$=\frac{n+y+2y+\ldots+ny+o(y)-n}{y}=1+2+\ldots+n+o(1) \to \frac {n(n+1)}{2}$$

Cute solution...

Recall from the geometric series summation formula that:
$$x + x^2 + x^3 +\ldots+ x^n = \frac{x^{n+1} - x}{x - 1}$$
Thus, the limand can be expressed as:
$$f(x) = \frac{\frac{x^{n+1} - x}{x - 1} - n}{x-1}$$
$$f(x) = \frac{x^{n+1} - x - n(x - 1)}{(x-1)^2}$$
Now, let's evaluate $f$ at points close to but not equal to 1.  If $x = 1 + \epsilon$, then:
$$f(1 + \epsilon) = \frac{(1 + \epsilon)^{n+1} - (1 + \epsilon) - n\epsilon}{\epsilon^2}$$
$$= \frac{1 + (n+1)\epsilon + \frac{(n+1)n}{2}\epsilon^2 + O(\epsilon^3) - (1 + \epsilon) - n\epsilon}{\epsilon^2}$$
$$= \frac{\frac{(n+1)n}{2}\epsilon^2 + O(\epsilon^3)}{\epsilon^2}$$
$$= \frac{(n+1)n}{2} + O(\epsilon)$$
Similarly, if $x = 1 - \epsilon$, then:
$$f(1 - \epsilon) = \frac{(1 - \epsilon)^{n+1} - (1 - \epsilon) - n(-\epsilon)}{\epsilon^2}$$
$$= \frac{1 - (n+1)\epsilon + \frac{(n+1)n}{2}\epsilon^2 + O(\epsilon^3) - (1 - \epsilon) - n(-\epsilon)}{\epsilon^2}$$
$$= \frac{\frac{(n+1)n}{2}\epsilon^2 + O(\epsilon^3)}{\epsilon^2}$$
$$= \frac{(n+1)n}{2} + O(\epsilon)$$
So, you're incorrect that “this function is not two sided”.  Both right and left sides approach the same limit.
